# JavaScript/Php strange mishap, data became a key?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code:

```
    javascript: (function () {   
    var jsCode = document.createElement('script');   
    jsCode.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');                    
    document.body.appendChild(jsCode);
    var stuid = prompt("Please provide student id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        data: stuid,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
 }());
```

and the var_dump that came back was strange. I var_dumped the GET request and this is what i got..

```
 array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Why did it become the associative array's key? How can i avoid it?

I am sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, i am new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
 data: stuid,
```

The data variable needs key - value pairs, so you would need to do something like:

```
 data: { "id": stuid },
```